# Targeting Chrome 36 with babel

Tags: babeljs

So I'm having to build a webapp which has got to support Chrome 38. Looking at the version history this was late 2014 so is probably in ES5 territory.

I suspect that babel will have no problem with this as it's what it was built for but does anyone know of any possible challenges I might face with a 2014 browser? Is there anything babel cannot transpile away?

The first release will be a ReactJS/GraphQL app. Nothing too fancy at first.

Comment: The answer really depends on the webapp. If it has features that were not supported by browsers in 2014, you may have to use polyfills or similar techniques to ensure your app works correctly with the old browser.

Comment: I'm not TOO concerned about client-side as the interface (at least at first) is fairly straightforward. We do have some fancier D3 stuff to add a few releases down the line but apparently, the upgrade to modern Chrome will have happened by then. I just need to survive for a year on 38, tops #famouslastwords